# Remove and access variable amount of characters from beginning of string

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to remove and grab a variable amount characters from the beginning of a string.

For example: I receive "Genesis1:2" as a $_GET or $_POST variable and need to extract "Genesis" from the beginning to the string leaving the rest of the string so I can parse it.

I can't use "substr()" because, "Genesis1:2" could also come as "Gen1:2" which both mean the same.

My problem is I need to, in all reality somehow "explode" the string into something like:

```
Array 
( 
    [0]=>Genesis, 
    [1]=>1, 
    [2]=>2
)
Array 
( 
    [0]=>Gen, 
    [1]=>1, 
    [2]=>2
)
```

However, I never no how long the set of characters will be.

Thank you.

Comment: I am really bad at regexes and was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing that your answer completed but taking in account for a number at the beginning and maybe a dash within the numbers? For example: "1Tim:1:2-5" or "1Tim1-2" might be "Array([0]=>1Tim, [1]=>1,[2]=>2,[3]=>"-",[4]=>5)" or "Array([0]=>1Tim, [1]=>1,[2]=>"-",[2]=>2)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all`.

```
preg_match_all('~[a-z]+|\d+~i', $str, $matches);
```

This would match alphabets and digits separately.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gP1tP2/2)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you again. I am really bad at regexes and was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing that your answer completed but taking in account for a number at the beginning and maybe a dash within the numbers? For example: "1Tim:1:2-5" or "1Tim1-2" might be "Array([0]=>1Tim, [1]=>1,[2]=>2,[3]=>"-",[4]=>5)" or "Array([0]=>1Tim, [1]=>1,[2]=>"-",[2]=>2)"? Thank you

Comment: try `preg_match_all('~^\d?[a-z]+|[^:]~i', $str, $matches);`